# Using forfiles with multiple file types for search mask?

Tags: windows, search

Following command works fine with one type of files ,

```
forfiles -p "C:abc\del" -s -m *.exe -d -70 -c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Is it possible filter through multiple file extensions? `*.exe`, `*.dll`, `*.xyz`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not as nice as I hoped for but this oneliner can help out. Notice however that you can't use * as a filter because the IN function starts selecting files in that case.

```
for %G in (.exe, .dll, .xyz) do forfiles -p "C:abc\del" -s -m *%G -d -70 -c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Used [this](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for reference.

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to traverse the directory structure in a single pass and test each file extension with an `IF`.

```
forfiles -p c:\ -s  -c "cmd /c (if @ext==\"exe\" echo @path) & ( if @ext==\"dll\" echo @path) &  ( if @ext==\"xyz\" echo @path)"
```

Just remember to escape the inner quotes  `\"dll\"  instead of "dll"`, because the whole command is in a single string.