# Batch - Forfiles in loop with multiple file types

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file for converting certain file types. So I don't put more useless loops in the code, I wanted to put it into one loop.

This is my code so far:

```
cd "%inputdir%"
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *.tga /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (
  set "file=%%~A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set filenametmp=%outputdir%!file:~1,-4!.paa

  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  For %%A in ("!filenametmp!") do (
    Set foldertmp=%%~dpA
  )

  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  IF NOT EXIST "!foldertmp!" (
    mkdir "!foldertmp!"
  )
  endlocal

  cd !Convertfolder!
  Pal2PacE %inputdir%!file:~1! !filenametmp!
)
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719347/using-forfiles-with-multiple-file-types-for-search-mask) to improve the for loop into:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('for %%G in (.tga, .png) do 'forfiles /s /m *%%G /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"'') do (...
```

Unfortunately, it throws this error:

```
System cannot find file for %G in...
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think this code will do what you want.

```
for %%G in (.tga, .png) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *%%G /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (
    REM The ECHO below is just for testing.
    REM Put the code from inside your FOR loop here.
    ECHO %%A
  )
)
```

Comment: I'm having problems getting the editor to accept my code. I keep getting an error when I try to post a certain line. I'm trying to figure out the problem...bear with me.

Comment: Weird...I had to put the codeblock inside a block quote, otherwise the quotes around `"cmd /c echo @relpath"` were causing a problem and I'd get an error when I tried to post or update the answer.

Comment: Well, it almost works, got me further than before :D however, for some reason it finds only the types of the first one (.tga in this case, but when i change order it is .png) and for the other one it writes ERROR: Files of type "*.png" not found.

Comment: When I said it works for me, I meant with the `ECHO %%A`. Looking at your code, towards the end you have `CD !Convertfolder!`. That could be your problem. You are `CD`ing into another folder and then when the next `forfiles` command runs, it's running in another folder that doesn't contain any of the files of the type it's looking for.

Comment: Oh yes! That is exactly the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe, but have not tested:

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('for %%G in (.tga, .png) do forfiles /s /m *%%G /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (...

should work, and the quotes around the `forfiles` command are confusing the issue.

Comment: Well, I tried various combination of quotation marks before posting here, that wasn't an issue :)