# how to implement delete code in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have created batch file which starting & stopping celery services.

I want to implement code in batch file so that files older than week will be deleted.

**celery_restart.bat**

```
NET STOP "CeleryBeat"
NET START "CeleryBeat"
NET STOP "Celery2"
NET START "Celery2"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered using `logrotate`? Why did you use the `python` tag?

Comment: As I am using windows machine so not able to use logrotate so I have created batch file using which I am restarting celery services & able to rotate log file along with also. Celery create new log file every time I am restarting celery services using batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows:

```
ForFiles /p "your\folder\with\logs" /m *.log /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Add `/s` to delete log files in subfolders as well. If you want to delete all files in the folder older than 7 days, just remove the `/m *.log` option.

Comment: above code working. I also want to delete .pid files alongwith log files so is there any way to delete .pid files also with same line because currently I have used two lines one for .log & another for .pid.

Comment: I recommend running `ForFiles /?` from the command line - it's pretty self-explanatory (literally). However to do what you want, there's no easy option - that question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719347/using-forfiles-with-multiple-file-types-for-search-mask (I would prefer the first solution given).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just run some for loops:

```
@echo off
set comms="CeleryBeat" "Celery2"
for %%i in (*.pid *.log do del %%i /Y
for %%a in (%comms%) do (
    net stop %%a && net start %%a
)
```

the `&&` operator here will start the service only if the previous command exited with `errorlevel` `0`